# "Generate XYZ tiles" tool does not fetch zoomed-in map from WMTS server in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts, xyz-tiles

I am trying to use QGIS to convert Swedish Latmateriet WMTS maps into OSM web tiles that I am using for my mobile app. Previously I used the Latmateriet's service directly, however after they updated the API, I was unable to force my mobile application (written in QT) to use authentication.

I used the RasterTool in QGIS (Generate XYZ tiles) to generate tiles. However, the problem is that zoomed-in tiles are really poor quality. It looks like the QGIS does not load zoomed-in images and generate tiles from the zoomed-out map. Is there a way to force QGIS to fetch deeper zoom levels while generating tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your wmts layer's resampling rules: if you set them to an interpolation and the factor is >1, tiles from higher zoomlevel will get used. This might help in this case.

You will have degraded image quality in any case though, as long as your scales and extents do not 100% match those of the wmts.